# Java 8 Stream: type mismatch cannot conver stream object ot list object

Tags: java, java-stream

Hi guys would like to ask am i doing the right why to assign a result set from stream to a variable? i am doing it like this but having some error

```
public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    customers.add(new Person(1, "test", "test", 25));
    customers.add(new Person(2, "test1", "test2", 3));
    customers.add(new Person(3, "test2", "test3", 62));

    List<Person> sList = customers.stream()
                                  .sorted();


}


}
```

I'm getting this error :

```
"type mismatch cannot convert stream<Person> to list<Person>"
```

Comment: If you're trying to sort your list, just use `List.sort()`. What's the stream for?

Comment: `sorted` is an intermediate operation you still have a stream after it. If you want to create a `List` from your stream you need to collect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change the statement from

```
List<Person> sList = customers.stream().sorted();
```

to

```
List<Person> sList = customers.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`sorted` returns stream instance which further allows performing additional operations like filter. Hence as per streams API, if you wish to grab the list instance, you should do so by calling `collect` method.

Comment: thanks for the response sir that resolve the errors but when i try to run this error will show dont know why?

 "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: lamdaTurorial.Person cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Comment: its ok now i just implement Comparable in my class :)